# How to set rangevalidator maximum value to value from stored procedure whose input value is taken from selected item in dropdown?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, stored-procedures, rangevalidator

Here's the scenario.
I have a dropdownlist which populates items. The dropdownlist items contains product id as value.
Now the quantity to be filled in the textbox needs to be validated using rangevalidator where the maximum value is to be taken from the database according to the selected item's product id.(I already have a stored proc to provide the maxquantity for corresponding productid).
How can I set the maximum value for the range validator for quantity.
Also I have used jquery plugin for the design of the dropdown and used clientside script for displaying price according to the product id as selectindexchanged is not fired.
Would anyone cast some light on this problem.

[image]

Comment: p.s Please line up your input's, my OCD is killing me right now :)

Answer (score 1):

To change the validator's maximum value in Javascript use:

```
var rvalid = document.getElementById('<%= RangeValidator1.ClientID %>');
rvalid.maximumvalue = 10;
```

For getting the maximum quantity from the stored procedure there are many solutions. You can do an Ajax call or you can store all the values immediately when the page renders.

How did you get the price value according to the ID? Maybe you should follow a similar approach here.

Comment: For the price value I have done binding of dropdownitem's value to productid/price/producttype (e.g 234/500/2). I could have used the similar approach for the itemquantity but it needs to  changes every time I select an item and again binding the whole dropdown with lots of items doesn't seem too good. Is there any other way around to do it easier..

Comment: Instead of a range validator you could use a custom validator and write server side code that invokes the stored procedure and validates the input

Answer (score 0):

Use a CustomValidator instead. Set the result of the SP to a Javascript variable and use it in the ClientValidate function.

Something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function CheckQuantity(sender, args)
  {
    if ($('#ddl').val()>maxQty)
         args.IsValid = false;
    else
         args.IsValid = true;
  }
</script>

<asp:CustomValidator
ControlToValidate="ddl"
OnServerValidate="CheckQuantity"
Text="Invalid quantity"
runat="server"/>
```

Comment: What I need to validate is the quantity text box according to the productid from dropdown. @Stefano Altieri thanks for the info but i didn't get what u mean.

Comment: In the CheckQuantity function you validate is the quantity text box according to the productid from dropdown and set args.IsValid accordingly.

Comment: Now what i did is; I just added an extra textboxe and with change in  the dropdownitem got product id in that textbox. document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value = prc[1]; After I got the productid, from codebehid i got the productquantiy and compared with the quantity entered. It works fine, however the problem is after I set the visiblity of the extra textbox to hidden.I can't get the value, how can i get the value with hidden textbox? Please Help dudes....

Comment: you can use an Hidden field instead